# How can I call a post-statement conditional on multiple statements?

Tags: perl

```
$df{key} =10 ; return ; if $result == 10 ;
```

gives me an error. How can I achieve this?

Comment: $df{key} = 10 and return if $result == 10;

Comment: I hope you've taken note of the caveat in my answer.

Comment: YES ...........................

Comment: If it gets complex, you probably should do a condition block, just because it's easier for others to understand that way. If you need a do ***block*** to do it with a post conditional, then you're *probably* putting too much at the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The post-statement form of `if` only works with single statements. You will have to enclose multiple statements in a block *after* the `if` condition, which itself needs to be enclosed in parentheses:

```
if ( $result == 10 ) {

    $df{key} = 10;
    return;
}
```

---

In this case, it is possible to combine the two statements with a post-statement conditional. The idea here is to combine the two statements in one by performing a Boolean evaluation.

However, this is **not** a good idea in general as it may short-circuit and fail to do what you expect, like when `$df{key} = 0`:

```
$df{key} = 10 and return if $result == 10;
```

---

From [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements):

> In Perl, a sequence of statements that defines a scope is called a block
>
> ... generally, a block is delimited by curly brackets, also known as braces. We will call this syntactic construct a BLOCK.
>
> The following compound statements may be used to control flow:
>
> `if (EXPR) BLOCK`
>
> `if (EXPR) BLOCK else BLOCK`
>
> `if (EXPR) BLOCK elsif (EXPR) BLOCK ... else BLOCK`

Answer (score 4):

You can group the statements into a `do BLOCK` and use a conditional
statement modifier on that compound statement.

```
do { $df{key} = 10; return } if $result == 10;
```

Unlike the `and` construct posted by Zaid, this is not ambiguous. You
should, however, think twice before using a conditional statement
modifier. Especially mixing `if`/`unless` statements with
`if`/`unless` statement modifiers reduces readability of your code.

The main case where in my opinion the statement modifiers make sense
are uncomplicated error paths, i.e.:

```
croak "foo not specified" unless exists $args{foo};
```

Comment: I know that `do { } while` is guaranteed to execute at least once. Does this mean that `do { } if` will do the same thing?

Comment: I just tried it. `do { print "hello\n" } if 0;` will print nothing, as expected.

Answer (score 4):

The [comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) allows one to chain together multiple statements into an expression, after which you can include the conditional:

```
$df{key} = 10, return if $result == 10;
```

I use this construct quite often when checking for error conditions:

```
for my $foo (something...)
{
    warn("invalid thing"), next unless $foo =~ /pattern/;
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the parentheses around the warning, or `warn` will gobble up `next`!

Comment: @Zaid: good point!  In my own code, `warn` is actually `$this->warn(...)` so the parentheses are already there... or I would have been bitten by this :)